# Check whether cronjob has ran or not

Tags: cron

I have one python script running in crontab, I want to check if it is running successfully or not? if not then send mail or another kind of notification. How do I notify based on Cron logs?

Things I already Tried:

- All the Exception in python file I have already handled

Need: Notify user if Cron job is not running successfully?

Answer (score 0):

In order to notify weather cron job running or not, you can set email id in cpanel **'cron jobs'** page. so you will receive email once file get executed.

Comment: I will be running cron job every 10 mins, so i want emails only when the execution fails,

Comment: is it possible to send email only when execution fails?

Answer (score 0):

There are monitoring services specifically for cronjobs, doing exactly what you're asking for. I'm partial to WDT.io and here're the detailed instructions: https://cookbook.wdt.io/cron.html.

Comment: hey @Chritstian thanks for your reply , is there any way without using third party software

Comment: You can build your own external monitoring solution. It's not super complicated, but will still take some time. So that only makes sense if your time is worth less than what these third party services charge.